# Java: Char Manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, char

Trying to sort an array of strings alphabetically without the use of the sort function. Code is as follows...

```
    public static String[] sortedAdjectives(String[] original)
{
    String[] sortedArray;
    String word;   
    sortedArray = new String[26];
    for(int i = 0; i <25; i++)
    {
        word = original[i];
        char c = word.charAt(0);
        sortedArray[c-'A'] = word;


    }
    return sortedArray;
}
```

It runs, but for some reason it's not sorting the array like I thought it would. In fact it's not sorting the array at all which confuses me even further. I'm passing it an array of 26 adjectives that I want sorted, and attempting to use Char subtraction to put it in the right index. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: This sorting method would broke if you sort `[Apple, Apes]`

Comment: True, but the data in the array is 26 adjectives, all with different first letters.

Comment: The "sort" algorithm you propose in your current code will only work -- and I hesitate to say that -- if the array of Strings you pass in all start with a capital letter, and no capital letter is represented more than once. That's a pretty narrow "working space" for a sorting function. If the challenge is to write your own lexicographical sort, then I'd recommend doing some searching on the topic. You'll find algorithms are well defined in this space, and hacks like you've posted are entirely unnecessary. Good luck!

Comment: [Prefer lists to arrays](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/generics/ch05lev1sec3)

Comment: Just a side note. I tested your code, it works fine for arrays of Strings that fit the narrow scoping I put in my prior comment. Likely your input has uppercase and lowercase first letters, or duplicate first-letter entries. Please post a sample of the input, post the error (if any) you get when you execute your function, and we can help further.

Comment: I found where I went wrong, thanks for the advice!